# Implementing own rotation function in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, algebra

I am trying to implement my own rotation function in OpenGL on C++, i.e. something like glRotate. My code for rotating around y looks like this:

```
void do_rotateY(GLdouble angle)
{
    //rotate around y axis
    GLdouble s = angle;
    GLdouble c[4][4];
    c[1][1] = c[3][3]= 1.0;
    c[0][0] = c[2][2] = cos(s);
    c[2][0] = sin(s);
    c[0][2] = -c[2][0];
    glMultMatrixd(*c);
}
```

When I'm doing a call like:

```
glPushMatrix();
do_rotateY(100);
...draw something...
glPopMatrix();
```

nothing appears on the screen. When I replace do_rotateY(...) with glRotatef(...) I can see everything correctly.

Comment: it looks like you aren't initializing all entries in the matrix. you can't assume c will be initialized to 0. you could explicitly init everything or just do the lazy thing and initialize c to identity before doing what you are currently doing.

Answer (score 4):

C++ `cos` and `sin` expect radian arguments, but you're passing degrees.

Everything else looks fine to me.

Comment: And just to mess with you further, `glRotate()` takes degrees! :)